# Remapping Ctrl + I with keysym in rxvt

Tags: terminal, tmux, xterm, rxvt

I'm trying to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to be captured as something else than tab, so I can use it as a shortcut in tmux.

However I cannot get to work. As a test case I tried to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  to output <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> with the following line for rxvt in `.Xresources`

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-i: \033w
```

and then map tmux

```
bind -n C-w select-pane -U
```

however, tmux ignores the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  and just outputs `^[w` to the terminal. Same with a non-tmux terminal window.

What am I doing wrong?